# Artifacts bulk update

Tags: python, ruby, api, rally

I understand [this was asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784748/rally-add-test-case-results-in-bulk-using-web-services-api), but that specific inquiry in their question was not resolved, so I’m asking again:

- Is there a way to update objects in bulk?

Like, I got a bunch of Test Results, or Defects, or whatever, ready to be uploaded to the server, but of course I would prefer to send just one chunk at a time, instead of one by one.

Something like:

```
{
  "TestCaseResult": {
    "Build": "2345",
    "Date": "2011-10-13T23:05:49.365Z",
    "TestCase": { 
      "_ref": "/testcase/12345678910.js"
     },
    "Tester": {
      "_ref: "/user/12345678911.js"
    },
    "Verdict": "Fail"
  },
  "TestCaseResult": {
    "Build": "11",
    "Date": "2011-10-14T23:05:49.365Z",
    "TestCase": { 
      "_ref": "/testcase/01234567891.js"
     },
    "Tester": {
      "_ref: "/user/12345678911.js"
    },
    "Verdict": "Pass"
  }
}
```

I ask because I think it’s not performant to be querying Rally servers all the time. At least not in cases like this, and also I don’t know if rally_api or pyral frameworks support it, should the API support it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can certainly understand how it would be useful to send an array of JSON objects to a Rally Endpoint in one go, and have the server handle the processing, instead of making one WSAPI call per Create or Update. Unfortunately, the way you are doing things, i.e. one call per TestCaseResult, is the way that WSAPI is structured for now. You may wish to visit [Rally Ideas](http://ideas.rallydev.com) to register a feature request for WSAPI vector create/update actions as a future enhancement.