# Rally Test case result update using Rest API

Tags: java, web-services, rest, testing, rally

There is a Rest Webservice URI for Test case result update in Rally.
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/testcaseresult/create

Can some one tell me what should be the payload for this?
May be point me to a working example.

I have searched this a lot for 2 days and could not find the information what I want.
The closest is: [Rally add test case results in bulk using web services API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784748/rally-add-test-case-results-in-bulk-using-web-services-api)

But however this did not help too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your payload?
What is the error you receive?
The post you refer to was correct for previous versions of WS API. v2.0 does not support XML, only JSON.

Minimally, the following fields must be set in the payload

```
"{"TestCaseResult":{"Build":"1","Date":"2014-09-04T19:56:05.000Z","TestCase":"/testcase/12358743669","Verdict":"Pass"}}"
```

Here is a full curl example. where double quotes are being escaped on Windows:

```
curl --header "zsessionid:_abc123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d"{\"TestCaseResult\":{\"Build\":\"1.0\",\"TestCase\":\"/testcase/12358743669\",\"Date\":\"2014-09-04T19:56:05.000Z\",\"Verdict\":\"Pass\"}}" https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/TestCaseResult/create
```

Since you used a java tag in your post, here is an example based on [Rally Java toolkit](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava).

```
public class addTCRtoTC {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "secret";
            String wsapiVersion = "v2.0";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";      
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/11111"; 
            String applicationName = "RestExample_AddTCR";

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        //Read User
        QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName", "SubscriptionAdmin"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "nick@wsapi.com"));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();  
        System.out.println(userRef);

        // Query for Test Case to which we want to add results
        QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
        testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID","Name"));
        testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "TC6"));
        QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);
        JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
        String testCaseRef = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("_ref").getAsString(); 

        try {
            for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {

                //Add a Test Case Result    
                System.out.println(testCaseRef);
                System.out.println("Creating Test Case Result...");
                JsonObject newTestCaseResult = new JsonObject();
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Verdict", "Pass");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Date", "2014-03-07T18:00:00.000Z");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Notes", "Some Scheduled Test");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Build", "2.0");
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Tester", userRef);
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("TestCase", testCaseRef);
                newTestCaseResult.addProperty("Workspace", workspaceRef);

                CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest("testcaseresult", newTestCaseResult);
                CreateResponse createResponse = restApi.create(createRequest);  
                if (createResponse.wasSuccessful()) {

                    System.out.println(String.format("Created %s", createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString()));          

                    //Read Test Case
                    String ref = Ref.getRelativeRef(createResponse.getObject().get("_ref").getAsString());
                    System.out.println(String.format("\nReading Test Case Result %s...", ref));
                    GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(ref);
                    getRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Date", "Verdict"));
                    GetResponse getResponse = restApi.get(getRequest);
                    JsonObject obj = getResponse.getObject();
                    System.out.println(String.format("my Read Test Case Result. Date = %s, Verdict = %s",
                            obj.get("Date").getAsString(), obj.get("Verdict").getAsString()));                 
                } else {
                    String[] createErrors;
                    createErrors = createResponse.getErrors();
                    System.out.println("Error occurred creating Test Case Result: ");
                    for (int j=0; i<createErrors.length;j++) {
                        System.out.println(createErrors[j]);
                    }
                }
            }


        } finally {
            //Release all resources
            restApi.close();
        }   

    } 

}
```

Comment: {  
   "TestCaseResult":{  
      "Build":"1",
      "Date":"2014-09-04T19:56:05.000Z",
      "TestCase":"What is this? Can I pass TC Id here?",
      "Verdict":"Pass"
   }
}How can I pass the user name of the tester, how can I pass the test set to which it belongs to??

Comment: Also, How can user pass the notes?? I tried with the payload you mentioned and got a response as following {
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "1",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "41",
        "Errors": [
            "Cannot parse input stream due to I/O error as JSON document: Parse error: expected ':' but saw '/' [ chars read = >>>{ \"TestCaseResult\" : {\n      \"Build\" : \"2345\",\n      \"Date\" : \"2014-11-17T23:05:49.365Z\",\n      \"TestCase\" : { \n          \"_ref\" : \"/testcase/12345678910.js\"\n        },\n      \"Tester\" : {\n          \"_ref : \"/<<< ]"
        ].....

Comment: It is test case ObjectID, you can't pass a Formatted ID. E.g. TC123 will not work. See the URL of the test case on which you want to create result, in the UI, e.g. https://rally1.rallydev.com/#/12352608219/detail/testcase/12358743669 The last string, 12358743669 is ObjectID of this test case. You can pass any valid field, but start slow. Make sure you can create a result by passing minimal required fields, and then gradually build on top of this in a "playground" environment.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Is there a way I can find out the standard payload that has all the tags/attributes for updating test case results?

Comment: Check required fields in the UI. For example, if in the UI you need to supply "Build" when creating TCR then "Build" has to be supplied when creating TCR via WS API.If you miss something, the error from WS API will tell you what field is needed, e.g. "Build cannot be null" or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

**Correct payload format:**

```
    {
        "TestCaseResult": {
            "Build": "1.0",
            "Date": "YYY-MM-DD",
            "TestCase": {
                "_ref": ""
            },
            "TestSet": {
                "_ref": ""
            },
            "Verdict": "Pass",
            "Workspace": {
                "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
                "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
                "_ref": "",
                "_refObjectUUID": "",
                "_refObjectName": "",
                "_type": "Workspace"
            }
        }
    }
```

**Header format:**
You can obtain the API key from [Rally Application manager](https://rally1.rallydev.com/login/accounts/index.html#/keys).

```
Rally_headers = {'ZSESSIONID' : API_KEY, 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', "Accept": "application/json"}
```

For more details read the document [here](https://github.com/HamiTheTank/RALLY-API-TestCaseResult).

Comment: Please make your answer useful even without a link.